# "Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture" in Ionic App

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using the video tag to load a video in my Page and I'm clickin' in the button to request full screen to video.

But doesn't work and the console show me this message:

> Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be
>   initiated by a user gesture.

What could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Google changed the Video tags API few days ago. I used Google's native 'Controls' for toggling the full screen when the user click it. But it failed too...I didn't understand why because it's the control rooted from the Google Chrome and the user click it so what security concern Google have to change the API ???